# 'NoneType' has no attribute 'lower'-- error when cleaning text

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, tfidfvectorizer

Below is my code I am running in databricks and below that is the error.

```
data = d.select("*").toPandas()
train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size = .20, random_state = True)
train['set'] = 'train'
test['set'] = 'test'
data = pd.concat([train,test], ignore_index=True)

def clean_text(text):
  return "".join([c for c in text.lower() if c not in punctuation])

data['text_cleaned'] = data['text'].map(clean_text)

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf.fit(data['text_cleaned'])
```

The error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
/local_disk0/tmp/1582551158268-0/PythonShell.py:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

/local_disk0/tmp/1582551158268-0/PythonShell.py:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  import 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: What are the contents of `data['text']`? Presumably it has some `None`s in there. You either need to fix whatever is producing them, or if they're expected, filter them out or convert them to some other value so `clean_text` doesn't receive them when you `map` the column.

Comment: I edited your question to add some code blocks around the error message. Is this one single error or are there 2 errors? I see it is complaining about line 3, and then line 4, which is kind of unusual... Can you confirm that this is exactly what the interpreter is printing, nothing more/nothing less?

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve].**

Comment: @Z4-tier here is the expanded part of the error

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-4098440727371123> in <module>
     13 
     14 # Clean the string labels
---> 15 data['text_cleaned'] = data['text'].map(clean_text)

Comment: /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   3380         """
   3381         new_values = super(Series, self)._map_values(
-> 3382             arg, na_action=na_action)
   3383         return self._constructor(new_values,
   3384                                  index=self.index).__finalize__(self)

Comment: /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
   1216 
   1217         # mapper is a function
-> 1218         new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
   1219 
   1220         return new_values

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

Comment: <command-4098440727371123> in clean_text(text)
     10 # Definne a simple convenience function for cleaning the strings
     11 def clean_text(text):
---> 12   return "".join([c for c in text.lower() if c not in punctuation])
     13 
     14 # Clean the string labels

Comment: @kcmox: Edit it into the question (and delete the comments), it's unreadable as comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out Nones:

```
data = d.select("*").toPandas()
train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size = .20, random_state = True)
train['set'] = 'train'
test['set'] = 'test'
data = pd.concat([train,test], ignore_index=True)

def clean_text(text):
    return "".join([c for c in text.lower() if (text is not None) and (c not in punctuation)])

data['text_cleaned'] = data['text'].map(clean_text)

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf.fit(data['text_cleaned'])
```